# Getting log4j error while running data driven testing code

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I am running the following data driven testing code but getting the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DataDriven_Ex {

    static WebElement searchbox;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
        WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("F://Selenium excel//DataDriven.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        int rowcount = sh.getLastRowNum();

        for (int i = 0; i<=rowcount;i++)
        {   
            String keyword = sh.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            searchbox.sendKeys(keyword);

            searchbox.submit();      
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the warning message, you should see full explanation at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig. You have to check if you supply a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` as part of the runtime classpath (i.e. that is accessible from Classloader at runtime).

Comment: How do i do that . Can you please explain me in detail

Comment: @Priyanka adding the following instruction at the begining of your test method may resolve your issue : `org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();`.

Comment: How do i supply log4j.properties as part of the runtime classpath

Comment: @priyanka Normally, you can tell log4j where is your log4j.properties file by using the system property **log4j.configuration**. For instance adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=./config/log4j.properties` option to the JVM that is running your tests.